# No rational point on a line equation

Tags: analytic-geometry

As such we know max rational points on a line can be atmost one in which slope is irrational .  I wonder if there are examples of line equation which has no rational point? Is it possible like taking √2x +√3y = 5 ? I dont have a proof yet .

Comment: Your example is fine.  Suppose $(x_0,y_0)$ was a rational point on  that line.  Now square  both sides and deduce that $\sqrt 6\in \mathbb Q$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @lulu understood

Comment: Note that you ought to handle the cases where either $x_0$ or $y_0$ is $0$, but those cases are easy.

Comment: A simpler example would be $x + y = \sqrt 2$, If $x$ is rational, then $y$ is not.

Comment: Nice example @PaulSinclair

Comment: Thanky you. I agree with lulu that your own example is fine, though. I was just pointing out a different approach. An even simpler example is $x = \sqrt 2$ ($y$ varies freely)>